# PHP: A class called 'static'

Tags: php, class, static

Is there a way around the following:

```
class static extends parents {
    // etc
}
```

Where 'static' is the name of the class and 'parents' is a legal extended class name.

The following throws this error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STATIC, expecting T_STRING
```

Any help/suggestions would be gratefully appreciated.

Comment: _static is not good? No, seriously, I don't know any workaround and I'm afraid there aren't any.

Comment: There is no way around this. static is a reserved word in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: Whats so special with `static` as a class name?

Comment: More info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792070/php-reserved-words-as-namespaces-and-class-names

Answer (score 5):

static is a **keyword**. You can not use them as a class name. In [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) its clearly stated.

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
>   which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but
>   they're not, really: they are language constructs. You cannot use any
>   of the following words as **constants, class names, function or method**
>   **names**. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
>   confusion.