# php namespace alias and the choice of words for directories - can we name a directory as global?

Tags: php, namespaces, alias

I am having more trouble with namespacing when comes to the choice of words after this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688805/php-namespace-alias-why-do-we-have-keep-the-classes-in-folders-when-autoload-is) I made earlier,

```
use \global\Conan as Cimmerian;
```

error message,

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'global' (T_GLOBAL), expecting
>   identifier (T_STRING) in C:\wamp..

So that's no way you can name a directory as **global** in this situation?

Comment: A list for the meaning of the `T_xxx` tokens is available here: http://www.php.net/tokens - You also might find the error messages reference useful: [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/367456)

Comment: Thanks for the links, hakre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`global` is a reserved keyword in PHP, so cannot be used as an identifier.

See the [List of Keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) in the PHP manual.

Although namespaces are not specifically mentioned on that page, they would cause the same problems as class names, in that the parser will not know what to do when it encounters the keyword - hence the error you are seeing.