# Need to create and use a class named "Array" but cannot

Tags: php, class, identifier

Is there any way to create and use a class named "Array" in PHP? So far, it seems to cause a name conflict with `array` programming construct, which is not a class.

Comment: Could you explain **why** you **need** to create a class named Array? Also: did you see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792070/php-reserved-words-as-namespaces-and-class-names)?

Comment: no. you can't. it'd be like trying to create a class named `new`. e.g. `$new = new New;`.

Comment: You can not use platform constants. You could use MyArray, hehahaah. Many other API's create their own wrappers, like ArrayCollection, etc

Comment: List of reserved keywords http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php

Comment: As you said, it's a `construct`, and hence you cannot. For the same reason you cannot have an `if` or `unset` class.

Comment: Wouldn't [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/ArrayObject) suit any use case? Explain your use case. (And yes, there would be a way to shoehorn a classname of "array", and an even more cumbersome way to instantiate it..)

Comment: @DesmondHume ok, keep avoiding answering legitimate questions (like: why would you want this in the first place?)

Comment: I needed `Array` class for an extremely interesting purpose, but I changed my mind about telling which one.

Comment: @DesmondHume Please DO elaborate. I don't see why you wouldn't (or can't) tell us and enlighten us?

Comment: @RobIII Prejudice and enlightenment ain't very compatible..

Comment: @DesmondHume I don't see why you seem so offended? Didn't I ask a normal question? By the way: there *might* be a way (using runtime code generation) but, even if it worked, it would cause more problems that it would (probably) solve. That's why it's important you tell us why you need this in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The class documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) states:

> The class name can be any valid label **which is not a PHP [reserved word](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.php)**.

Array is a [reserved word](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php) and, thus, you cannot. PHP has no way (AFAIK) to "escape" these words. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792070/php-reserved-words-as-namespaces-and-class-names).

You need to name your class more specifically (like `MyArray` or `AnimalList`).

Answer (score 1):

[Here is the list of reserved keywords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php). It's explicitly said :

> These words have special meaning in PHP. Some of them represent things
> which look like functions, some look like constants, and so on - but
> they're not, really: they are language constructs.
>
> You cannot use any of the following words as constants, **class names**, function or method
> names. Using them as variable names is generally OK, but could lead to
> confusion.

You've got plenty of alternatives to name your class ;)