# Using the word "array" in a "use" statement in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

I have the following:

```
use Twig\Loader\Array as Twig_Loader_Array;
```

I am hoping to use TWIG in my custom framework, and my autoloader isn't quite smart enough to load twig stuff, so I have to help it out.

Only problem is, the above line spits out:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in...
```

Uhhhh.. What?

Is it really thinking that the `...\Array` bit is trying to create an array???

How can I get around this? I can't change folder names because i'll break twig if I do.

Comment: why not? array's a keyword: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.keywords.php You'd get the same effect if you named it "Echo" or "For".

Comment: in that list, array() is a keyword, not Array... I suppose you are right though... I give up!

Comment: Can you use a different alias?

Comment: Well as I said, the actual folder is called "Array" and my autoloader uses that to find the classes...

Comment: From: https://kornel.ski/phpns 'Namespaced names are not tokens in the PHP parser (\ is a separator token), which means that use of a reserved word as any part of the namespace's “path” is a parse error.'

Comment: The thing to understand is that twig is not a namespaced library so any attempt to use the 'use' statement will fail.  The array issue is really just a diversion.  Just use: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Array() along with the standard composer autoload and you should be fine.

Comment: I would be using the standard autoloader but at work we are completely off-line as far as our Web servers go. (we host a lot of internal Web applications) so composer is pretty useless to us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use a reserved keyword as part of your namespace.

Also, `array` or `Array` make no difference.
PHP is case insensitive for its keywords (same for conditions, method names, class names , ...).

See [PHP reserved words as namespaces and class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792070/php-reserved-words-as-namespaces-and-class-names)

Plus, the `Twig_Loader_Array` doesn't have any namespace.
The only thing you have to do is use it like `new \Twig_Loader_Array(/* ... */)`

For more informations, see the [Twig API](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Loader_Array.html)

To get around this problem, just use [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) to manage your vendors and register your app in the `autoload` part of your `composer.json`.

Example :

```
// composer.json

// ...

"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "YourNamespace\\YourLib": "src/"
    }
},

// ...
```